# NGINX reverse proxy to a web gui not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have an issue with nginx reverse proxy to Cisco vManage web ui.
The setup is:

- A GNS3 server with a vManage running on it
- nginx in docker running on the same server, nginx is needed on order to simplify access to the systems running inside GNS3

When logging in directly, without nginx, i see that login is done using a POST call to vmanage_address/j_security_check and the reply contains the login token and location header, pointing to vManage dashboard.

[image]

However, when logging in via nginx there is no location header:
[image]

The nginx proxy config is very simple:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 10.23.2.202;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.122.2:8443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
} }
```

Apparently something is needed to preserve the location header.

Addition: Another observation is that on the first screenshot, when connecting wihtout nginx the server response is 302, which is "Page temporary moved", while on the second screenshot, when using nginx the response code is 200, which is why, apparently, it has no location.

Comment: Hi. Did you try with a trailing slash for the `proxy_pass` ? `proxy_pass https://192.168.122.2:8443/;`

Comment: @Philippe yes, I did, the result is the same.